# Mapping JSON value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary

I try create a select option list with plain Javascript and a JSON file.

The issue is that the name of the last dog "Big Loser", isnt complete.

I only get "Big"

dogSelect.js

```
import someDogs from '../../data/someDogs.json'

export default class DogSelection {
  constructor () {}

  initialize (element) {
    element.innerHTML = `
    <h2>Select a dog</h2>

    <p>Dogs : <span></span></p>
    <select id="dogs"></select>
    
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name :</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="name" value="" /><br />
        <label>Age :</label><br />
        <input type="number" name="age" value="" /><br />
        <label>Race :</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="race" value="" /><br />
      </div>
    </form>
    `
    this.dogsListEl = element.querySelector('select');
    this.dogsListEl.innerHTML = this.addDogs();

  }

  addDogs(){
    let dogsList = '';
    manyDogs.map(dog => {
      dogsList += this.addDogOption(dog['name']);
    })
    return dogsList;
  }

  addDogOption(dogName){
    return `<option value=${dogName}>${dogName}</option>`;
  }
}
```

someDogs.json

```
[
  {
    "name": "Keven",
    "age": 3,
    "breed": "Retriever"
  },
  {
    "name": "Jaskier",
    "age": 2,
    "breed": "Weiner"
  },
  {
    "name": "Big Loser",
    "age": 4,
    "breed": "Labrador"
  }
]
```

So my guess is that the space between "Big Loser" is separating the two word and only the first one is returned by the map function.

I tried using brackets.
I tried using properties as dog.name.
I tried creating an array of dogs name.

Does anyone have an idea on this issue?

Comment: If I remove the " " or replaces it with a "_" everything works but I absolutely need to keep the space.

Comment: You need to add quotes around the value of the `value` attribute. (So `value="${dogName}"`.)